# How to insert Plotly div in specific places in HTML file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, plotly

I have an HTML template and I would like to insert plotly figures in specific places in the HTML file. I have three figures and use the following code to add the figures to the HTML file:

```
figures= [fig1, fig2, fig3]
    
with open('test.html', 'a') as f:
    for fig in figures: 
        f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=True))
```

When I do that it adds all three figures at the bottom of the file, after the rest of the code in the template. Does anyone know how I can add each of the three figures after the appropriate headers? I think I read somewhere that I can do this with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Yes you can do that via `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Can you show an example of how I can do that?

Comment: It would be easy to answer your query if you put some html and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
import chart_studio.tools as tls

tls.get_embed('https://plotly.com/~chris/1638')
```

Based on the documentation [link] [https://plotly.com/python/embedding-plotly-graphs-in-HTML/#:~:text=Plotly%20graphs%20can%20be%20embedded,Plotly%20graphs%20with%20the%20plotly](https://plotly.com/python/embedding-plotly-graphs-in-HTML/#:%7E:text=Plotly%20graphs%20can%20be%20embedded,Plotly%20graphs%20with%20the%20plotly). the above code should do it for you. There is a lot of examples at this link as well.[link]https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/